# Prove that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N(\epsilon) $ such that $\left| \frac{k+3}{k^2-5k} \right| < \epsilon, \forall k > N$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N(\epsilon) $ such that:

$$\left| \frac{k+3}{k^2-5k} \right| < \epsilon, \forall k > N$$

This is what I have so far, for k > 5:

$$\frac{k+3}{k(k-5)} < \epsilon, \forall k > N$$
$$\frac{k+3}{k} \times \frac{1}{k-5} < \epsilon, \forall k > N$$
$$\frac{k+3}{k} \times \frac{1}{k-5} < \frac{k+3}{k} < \epsilon, \forall k > N$$

I'm not too sure where to go next.

Comment: What justifies the last inequality ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is easy. You can see that $\frac{k+3}{k^2 -5k}$ is a quantity which tends to $0$ when $k$ is sufficiently large since 
$$\lim_{k--+\infty}\frac{k+3}{k^2 -5k}=\lim_{k--+\infty}\frac{k}{k^2}=\lim_{k--+\infty}\frac{1}{k}=0$$ so we can reformulate the fact that the quantity
 $\frac{k+3}{k^2 -5k}$ tends to $0$ when $k$ is large as the following:
$\forall \epsilon>0,$ there exists $N=N(\epsilon)$ means depending on $\epsilon$ such that for $k>N$ (means $k$ is large) we have $|\frac{k+3}{k^2 -5k}-0|<\epsilon.$
Good luck! Khadija

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have an expression with numerator linear in $k$ and denominator quadratic: in general take an expression with polynomial expressions in both numerator and denominator with the former of smaller degree, then the same holds with absolute values.